# Pi4J : Detect all plugged devices

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, gpio, pi4j

Is there a way to detect GPIO plugged devices using Pi4J ? Indeed, using GpioController object, you can get and change the state of the pin but not the presence/absence of device on it.

I may use it mainly for relays and DS18B20 devices.

If not maybe using another method (eventually using another language/library) like scanning all pins and detecting the presence of a device ?

Comment: To detect a device you'd have to probe it. This is only possible if you know what device is connected and how it behaves. Also probing might mean that you get unwanted side effects e.g if there is a power line  or valve connected to a pin you might inadvertently switch it on or off.